# Django doesn't serve all js files in development

Tags: javascript, django

I have two js files in my static folder, main.js and animation.js. When I run `py manage.py runserver` and go to localhost, I only see main.js. I've tried hard refreshing Chrome and Firefox, running collectstatic, and it's still the same. One time when I first loaded the page I saw both js files, but after clicking around the site, the animation.js file just disappeared. My terminal output shows that both js files were found. I'm confused why only one shows up in the browser. If both were missing that would indicate something wrong in settings, but I don't know with just one missing. What could be my problem?

Here's my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = TRUE
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

I include the js files in my base.html which every page extends:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'js/animation.js' %}"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Justin, can you please show your browser console ? And also your HTML file where you including these js files.

Comment: I added the html file that includes them. The console doesn't show anything.

Comment: The console shall show the network requests under Network tab, so you know what was requested and what is the server response

Comment: What is the output if you type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/animation.js` in your browser address bar?  This could be a variety of things.  In my case, which I can see is not yours, I typed the `src` attribute of `<script>` tag incorrectly as `scr`.  Also, your `animation.js` `<script>` tag has the `type="module"` attribute.  Try removing that attribute or does the file have an `export` command?

Comment: What if you removed **type="module"** from the animation script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue was an error caused by an import problem in the module script.